# Getting TypeError when instantiating class with a base class

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm using [Pint](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to play with some unit conversions, and was trying to inherit one of Pint's `Quantity` classes to make an Ingredient class. It works fine however when I have another argument in the `__init__` definition, I get a `TypeError`:

```
# This is how their docs say to initialize the Quantity class
from pint import UnitRegistry

ureg = UnitRegistry()
Quantity = ureg.Quantity

class Ingredient(Quantity):
    def __init__(self, name=None, quantity=0, units=None):
        super(Ingredient, self).__init__(quantity, units)
        self._name = name


i = Ingredient('Milk', 3, 'cups')
```

This produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pathToFile\myFile.py", line 14, in <module>
    i = Ingredient('Milk', 3, 'cups')
TypeError: __new__() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I'm assuming it's because `Quantity` requires 2 arguments by default but really not too sure. Also if my terminology was off, please feel free to correct me

Comment: Apparenrly `Quantity` overrides `__new__`, so you would have to override it in your subclass as well.  It's not clear to me that your class should really inherit from `Quantity` though.  It seems like your "ingredient" just be an object that *has* a quantity, not something that *is* a quantity.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yea, I was just playing around but you're probably right, thanks for clearing that up for me though.